# How do I attach a JDialog box to Eclipse's event loop?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Long story short:  How does one get Eclipse's main JFrame or JWindow to pop up a dialog box?

I am working with an Eclipse plugin that allows GUI Selection Events (i.e. selecting a variable, class name, then you see it highlight) to dynamically execute a special function in different Java classes, given that the classes implement a certain interface.  I'm writing one of these classes, and I need to use a pop up box to ask the user for some information.

Comment: Note: Eclipse uses SWT not Swing

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I expected.  I literally just did a static call to `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` which returns a `String` value.  Stupid question.